# Как обнулить input после записи в перемунную?

Tags: javascript

```
   <input class="qty__item" id="addd" type="number" />
    <button class="product-box__btn" onclick="go()">Добавить</button>
    <script>
    function go() {
        let zum = document.getElementById('addd').value;
        ...
    }
    </script>
```

Записали в zum значение которое выбрал пользователь, как обнулить значение input после нажатия?

Comment: `document.getElementById('addd').value = ""`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function go() {
  let zum = document.getElementById('addd').value;
  document.getElementById('addd').value = '';
  console.log('addd-value - ' + document.getElementById('addd').value)
  console.log('zum - ' + zum)
}
```

```html
<input class="qty__item" id="addd" type="number" />
<button class="product-box__btn" onclick="go()">Добавить</button>
```

Comment: Почему не работало с zum = ''; ???

Comment: Все сработало... Почему не сработало

Comment: `zum` тоже обнулиться при повторном нажатии